# EF Core 2.1 DbFunctions does not contain a definition for 'FreeText'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use the FreeText function in EF Core 2.1 that was added as part of https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11481

My project has the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.2" />
```

But I cannot get FreeText to register - getting the following error:

```
 'DbFunctions' does not contain a definition for 'FreeText' and no extension method 'FreeText' accepting a first argument of type 'DbFunctions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is my code, and at the top I have an import for using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

```
return await _context.Insights
    .Where(f => EF.Functions.FreeText(f.Heading, query))
```

Comment: Do you have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll added in the project?

Comment: I'm running on a mac, can you add Dll's on a mac?

Comment: U didn’t mention Mac in your question

Comment: Well it's .net core, it's cross platform, it shouldn't matter :-)

Comment: Run ‘dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer from application directory

Comment: Same issue, as per my original question though, you can see that I already have the package reference

Comment: When you type `.` after `Functions` what does IntelliSense show you?

Comment: GetType and Like

Comment: Can you navigate (Go to definition) to type `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions`? It should contain the extension method in question.

Comment: No luck The type or namespace name 'SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: This means you have wrong EF Core package. Install latest package `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.2.0-preview1-35029 -IncludePrerelease`

Comment: Are you sure the project where this code is executing *really* references Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.2? The class and the `FreeText` (along with many other) are there.

Comment: As far as I can see yes, I did a dotnet restore.  When I go to definitions on the functions type I can see at the top of the file #region Assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60

Comment: I created a new project and it works, something definately wrong with my .net version.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you tell your new project’s congratulation